# Imagemagick convert command not working through PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to run imagemagic command throught PHP, this command working perfectly from command prompt but not from PHP, what can be the issue. Other simple convert commands are working through PHP

```
convert -size 101x111 -background none -fill '#fcfcfc' -pointsize 15 label:'Whitesdd' -trim \/var/www/html/clients/kahuna.in/uploads/kukui_single_nut_image/14925222350_color.png +swap -gravity center -composite \/var/www/html/clients/kahuna.in/uploads/kukui_single_nut_image/14925222350.png
```

Through PHP

```
system("convert -size 101x111 -background none -fill '#fcfcfc' -pointsize 15 label:'Whitesdd' -trim \/var/www/html/14925222350_color.png +swap -gravity center -composite \/var/www/html/14925222350.png 2>&1", $var);

output os
convert: not authorized `Whitesdd' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/454. convert: no such image `/var/www/html/14925222350_color.png' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageList/8221. convert: no images defined `/var/www/html/14925222350.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3046.
```

Comment: FWIW, there's a [PECL ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extension you can use with native PHP so you don't have to shell exec.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your result is supposed to look like but this should work without creating any errors:

You only need a relative path to the image which may have been the problem
Writing the code like this means you can echo the command when using variable that will help fault find.
It also splits the code up into readable chunks.
You could probably use parenthases to help control the code.

Out of interest I do not use the imagemagick API ( imagick ) as I find it does not support a lot of the options and you need to write more code.

```
<?php
$cmd = "-size 101x111 -background none -fill '#fcfcfc' ".
" -pointsize 15 label:'Whitesdd' -trim input.png +swap ".
"-gravity center -composite 14925222350.png ";

exec("convert $cmd 14925222350.png ");
?>
```

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned. Command is working fine on command prompt and giving desired output but when I copy same command in exec its giving above error.

Comment: Did you try my PHP code? Did you get any error messages? Your code uses the output image twice. So does Bonzo's code. Does your system limit you from using exec()?

Comment: Hi I tried your code, same output. No system allow exec, I tried simple convert command which worked perfectly. But when I am trying convert with label option its not working.

Comment: Hi I tried your code, same output. System allow exec command as I tried simple convert command which worked perfectly. But when I am trying convert with label option its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible issues.

First, you have your output image, 14925222350.png, specified twice in your code, first in the cmd and second in the php convert.

Second, try adding the full path to convert.

Try this to see what error messages you get:

```
<?php
exec("path2/convert $cmd 2>&1",$out,$returnval);
foreach($out as $text)
{echo "$text<br>";}
?>
```

Where you can try without the path2/ or provide your path to convert.

Comment: Hi, yes tried adding full path as well. Same output. Also as I said simple convert command is working through PHP but when I try command with label its not work in PHP